# What are possibilities that <sessionState> timeout is ignored when using forms authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

We are running a MVC application on .NET 4.5 and I am playing with the session timeouts of sessionState and forms authentication:

web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2" />
  </authentication>
  <!-- some more tags ... -->
</system.web>
```

According to this, I think I should be logged out after 1 minute of inactivity, but I don't. I do get logged out after 2 minutes.

I am wondering why this is? We don't save or store anything in the session, but does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session state is not tied to your logged in state. You can be logged in, but have multiple sessions be created and abandoned, all without logging out.

This is a plausible sequence of events:

1. Session Starts
2. User Logs in
3. Session times out
4. Session Starts
5. Session times out
6. Session Starts
7. User Logs out
8. Session times out

Comment: Thanks, I get it, but then, what is the use of the timout of sessionState?

Comment: @Martijn To time out a session. Let's say you're shopping on a website, not logged in (so no authentication is involved). You add items to your cart (and the shopping cart is stored in Session). As a developer, perhaps after a while you want that session to end so you can reclaim the memory or database space. So you set a session timeout.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I never really thought about it, but it is clear now. Thanks again :)